# Error when uploading app with Application Loader: ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was build with the iOS 11.4 SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk, application-loader

I have **Swift 3.2** project and I am developing this old project with **Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)** because Xcode 10.2.1 does not accept old Swift languages like Swift 3.2 which is a shame.

So I developed my application in the Xcode 9.4.1 and I want to upload on the App Store. **I archived this app on the Xcode 9.4.1.**

I tried to upload app all Xcode version and all way. I tried to upload with using Xcode 9.4.1 and Xcode 10.2.1. I try on **Application Loader** which is Xcode 9.4.1 and Xcode 10.2.1. And there is gives same error all the time.

This is the error message and screen:

> ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS
>   11.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later. Furter,
>   starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be
>   built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or
>   later."

[image: error image]

I have already added all SDK of iOS to my Xcode 9.4.1

[image]

**How can I upload this app with old version?**

Comment: You can't. As the message says you must use the 12.1 SDK, which means Xcode 10.1 as a minimum. You will need to convert to Swift 4 or 5

Comment: Now is there any way to upload an app into the App Store with Swift 3?

Comment: No, you need to convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Uploading Swift 3 projects is complicated now in 2019 but doable.

I can use **Xcode 10.1 with Swift 3**. I am *developing* and *archived* my app in **Xcode 10.1**. When I tried *distribute app on Xcode 10.1 "Certificate: Unknown" came on Summary*. So I upload app (**Distribute App**) on **Xcode 10.2.1** which is the last version of Xcode.